# CorePlot : 2 Y axes using different plot spaces - formatting issue

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have two y-axes with different scales. So I added another plot space. I used the same xRange for the second plot space, but use a different yRange, e.g.,

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
plotSpace2.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(ymin)
                                             length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(ymax2 - ymin)];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2;
```

I have also added the y2 axis to the axisSet after configuring it.

```
graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];
```

To make the x axis intersect the left y axis, I have used the following.

```
axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-4");
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-0.5");
```

How can I do the same with the y2 axis? I would like the x axis to intersect the y2 axis at the point `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orthogonal coordinate for the X axis has to be relative to one Y axis or the other, not both. If you have two plot spaces with different yRanges, I think you can achieve what you want by setting the orthogonal coordinate for the X axis relative to your left Y axis, then adjust the yRange for plotSpace2 so that the X axis intersects Y2 at the desired coordinate.

```
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-0.5");

// Adjust yRange as needed to get the axis to intersect where you want it to
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:(CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(ymax2 - ymin2)];
```

Comment: But that makes the y axis intersect the x axis at x = -1. I would like to make the intersection at y = -1.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking for.  The orthogonal coordinate for the X axis has to be relative to one Y axis or the other, not both.  If you have two plot spaces with different yRanges, I think you can achieve what you want by setting the orthogonal coordinate for the X axis relative to your left Y axis, then adjust the yRange for plotSpace2 so that the X axis intersects Y2 at the desired coordinate.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to your correct understanding of the question.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect correct understanding of the question.  Hope it helps.